# Conexion Node Js Mariadb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mariadb

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una conexión entre nodejs y mariadb por medio de Xampp, pero cuando corro estó no me devuelve nada, me debería de devolver el 1 que genera el query, pero nadamás no me manda nada. Alguien sabe en donde estoy fayando?

```
// db

const mariadb = require('mariadb');


const pool = mariadb.createPool({ // Open a new connection                                                                                                                                           
    host: '192.168.64.2', 
    user:'EdAdmin', 
    password: '123456',
    database : 'TUsers',
    port:3000
});

pool.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {

      conn.query("SELECT 1 as val")
        .then((rows) => {
          console.log(rows); //[ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]
          //return conn.query("INSERT INTO myTable value (?, ?)", [1, "mariadb"]);
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res); // { affectedRows: 1, insertId: 1, warningStatus: 0 }
          conn.end();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle error
          conn.end();
        })

    }).catch(err => {
      //not connected
    });
```

Comment: Seguro pruebas tal cual te indico? Amplia tu pregunta por qué este código me funciona en un entorno igual

Comment: ¿Eres consciente de que si conectas a una BBDD desde Javascript (entiendo que a través de la librería Node JS) las credenciales de acceso a esa BBDD (url, usuario y password esencialmente) van a ser públicos a cualquiera que pulse Ctr+U o dé con el botón derecho del ratón sobre la página y le diga "Ver código fuente de la página"?
De hecho, el principal motivo por el que las conexiones a las BBDD se hace con php es porque php se ejecuta en el servidor (al contrario que Javascript, que se ejecuta en el host) y su código sólo es visible si alguien descarga el fichero php desde tu servidor. De to

Comment: Hola Fran. Tengo curiosidad. Tienes a mano un ejemplo de conexión a MariaDB/MySQL desde el browser como para no hacerlo?

Comment: Node JS no es una librería, es _un entorno en tiempo de ejecución para la capa del servidor_. De todas maneras, lo tuyo es un (largo) comentario, no una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Te saludo y te comento que tu consulta debería quedar de este modo; considerando que:

El conector de `mariadb` permite trabajar la conexión por medio de:

1. Promises
2. Async & Await

Para este caso usaremos el caso de `async & await`

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb')

const conecta = mariadb.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password:'pass',
    database: 'database',
    port: '3307'
})

let fetchData = async () => {
    let conecction
    try{
        conecction = await conecta.getConnection()
        const filas = await conecction.query("SELECT 1 as val")
        filas.forEach((fila) => {
            console.log(fila)
        })
    }catch(err){
        return err
    }
}

fetchData()
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Creamos la conexión asignandola a `conecta`
2. Mediante una función asíncrona; obtenemos el valor de la conexión
3. A la variable `filas` le asignamos al acceso al método `query` para ejecutar `SELECT 1 as Val`
4. Mediante un `forEach` recorremos los valores que nos trae el arreglo contenido en `filas` y lo asignamos en la variable `filas`
5. Al final mandamos llamar la función por medio de su nombre `fetchData`

**Resultado final**

Deberías obtener por consola, algo similar a lo siguiente

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\project>node app.js
{ val: 1 }
```

**ACLARACIÓN**

Si no recorres a la variable `filas` por medio de un `forEach`; entonces la consola te devolverá un resultado similar al siguiente

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\project>node app.js
[ { val: 1 },
  meta: [ { collation: [Collation],
      columnLength: 1,
      columnType: 3,
      scale: 0,
      type: 'LONG',
      flags: 129,
      db: [Function: bound getStringProperty],
      schema: [Function: bound getStringProperty],
      table: [Function: bound getStringProperty],
      orgTable: [Function: bound getStringProperty],
      name: [Function: bound getStringProperty],
      orgName: [Function: bound getStringProperty] } ] ]
```

Referencias

- [Doc oficial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero desafortunadamente no pasa nada , mi terminal se queda en espera cuando lo corro

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim dime que versión de NodeJS tienes y que versión de conector de mariaDB estas usando?

Comment: node : v8.11.4 y mariadb : v10.0.17

Comment: Estaba pensando que podría ser el puerto, intente cambiandolo por 80, es que simplemente no me da respuesta ... como si nunca llegara a confirmar la conexión o a hacerse

Comment: mariadb es el único servidor de bases de datos que tienes? por que este se instala como mysql por defecto en el 3306 en caso contrario dime en que puerto lo instalaste

Comment: si es el único que tengo estoy usando xampp 7 para mac, en ambos casos usando tu código o el mío , no avanza ni tira nada, ya probé con 3000, 80, 8080 y 3306, pero supongo que me mandaría algo si fuese el puerto

Comment: ok encontré en el httpd.conf que xampp corre en el puerto 80 e hice algunos cambios para que ,e tire un error y me tira esto: > not connected due to error: Error: retrieve connection from pool timeout e hice esto > 
conecta.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {
      console.log("connected ! connection id is " + conn.threadId);
      conn.end(); //release to pool
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("not connected due to error: " + err);
    });